# executing a ksh script does not inherit environment variables

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, centos7, ksh

I'm trying to run a simple shell ( Centos 7 ) that print out the system HOSTNAME variable:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "HOSTNAME:"$HOSTNAME
```

when executed from bash or ksh the shell does not work as expected

```
>ksh ./test.sh ----> HOSTNAME is unset
>./test.sh ----> HOSTNAME is unset
```

if i create a ~/.profile that declare and export HOSTNAME nothing change.
if i crate a ~./kshrc that source ~./profile works only if i switch from bash to ksh and execute the script.

if i run from bash the following code it does work due to the interactive mode

```
ksh -xi ./test.sh

+ command . ./.profile
+ HOSTNAME=<MYNAME>
+ export HOSTNAME
+ export HOSTNAME
+ echo HOSTNAME:<MYNAME>
HOSTNAME:<MYNAME>
```

without interactive mode ~/.profile is not loaded

```
+ echo HOSTNAME:
HOSTNAME:
```

I need to have original HOSTNAME set even in ksh due to a bunch of scripts that use HOSTNAME variable

PS: i've tried printing PATH variable and it's working even when HOSTNAME does not

Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: You need to `export HOSTNAME`. This is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Your `.kshrc` should almost certainly not source `.bashrc`. If you want to share settings, put them in `.profile` - and make sure you don't use any Bash or Ksh syntax - and then `source` that from your shell-specific startup files if necessary. (For example, Bash prefers `.bash_profile` over `.profile` if both exist; the former should usually `source` the latter.)

Comment: If the variable is already `export`ed, something is replacing its value. If this is a private variable of yours, don't use uppercase because that conflicts with a system variable. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: Without access to your startup files, it's haid to tell. Read the `ksh` manual page and/or experiment with its debugging options (guessing `ksh -xi`; not in a place where I can test).

Comment: `.profile` vs `.bashrc` is probably unrelated to your problem, but overloading `.bashrc` for stuff which isn't specific to Bash is generally problematic. The `.profile` file is available for precisely this purpose.

Comment: Probably [edit] your question to include these debugging efforts, and delete these comments - your question should be self-contained. It's still not clear if you want to override the system variable of the same name, or just unluckily gave your private variable a name which clashes with the reserved system variable (in which case the trivial fix is to rename it to lower case, and generally avoid uppercase for your private variables).

Comment: @tripleee thanks edited original message . hope it's more clear

Comment: are any other system variables working like PATH? echo them and see if that works, then I would detect where those are defined .... maybe /etc/profile or your home dir profile....

Comment: The root problem here is probably that `HOSTNAME` is reserved by Bash. It will be automatically set when you are running Bash; perhaps your scripts which require this variable should then be changed to require Bash (`#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` in the shebang, etc), or use a different variable name if you don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

When I put

```
HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)
export HOSTNAME
```

in my .kshrc - if you don't have it, create it, I got this working and was able to

```
echo $HOSTNAME
server
```